# Can you draw a weapon as part of a spell attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, action-economy

This is inspired by the following question which seems to only ask about *steel wind strike*, while this question is more general:

- [Can I draw a weapon as a part of a Melee Spell Attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179229)

---

The rules on "[Other Activity on Your Turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn)" state (emphasis mine):

> [...] You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or **you could draw your weapon as part of the same action you use to attack.** [...]

Similarly, the rules on the "[Use an Object](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UseanObject)" action state (emphasis mine):

> You normally interact with an object while doing something else, such as when **you draw a sword as part of an attack.** When an object requires your action for its use, you take the Use an Object action. [...]

However, what if you cast a spell such as [*fire bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-bolt), which involves making an attack; can you draw a weapon while performing this attack?

Comment: Do you mean draw a weapon using your free object interaction? Or besides free object interaction, drawing a weapon as a part of the attack?

Comment: @enkrtptor The question I asked was more or less just a bad question. I got hung up on the idea of "you can draw a weapon as part of an attack" being a *rule* and not just an *example* of one way to use your free object interaction in the middle of your action. So I was asking about something that doesn't really even exist whose answer is just that you can draw a weapon during *any* action, not just when making an attack

Comment: To my knowledge, "draw a weapon as part of an attack" and "draw or sheathe a sword" as an example of free object interaction are two different things. So you can expend your free object interaction and still be able to draw a weapon as part of an attack.

Comment: @enkryptor I am fairly certain drawing a weapon as part of your attack *does* use your object interaction. It's listed as an example use as far as I can tell. Though feel free to ask a question on it

Comment: You're probably correct. I've checked this case in the PHB — it was about loading ammunition, not drawing a weapon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes, it is done in tandem with the Cast a Spell action.

The rules for object interactions state:

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action.

The rules then give an example:

> Here are a few examples of the sorts of thing you can do in tandem with your movement and action:
>
> - draw or sheathe a sword

Since casting *firebolt* uses your action, you may draw your sword.

#### I have never played with a DM who much cared for the strict reading of this rule.

I've played with a lot of DMs. Not once has a DM objected to drawing my sword without moving or taking an action. Yes, it does say it must be done in tandem with either your move or action. So in a strict reading, it would seem you have to either move or take an action to interact with an object, but this is obviously a silly ruling:

> Player: I draw my sword.
>
> DM: Are you moving or taking an action?
>
> Player: No? I just need to have my sword out.
>
> DM: You can only interact with objects if you take some other action or move.
>
> Player: Okay? I use my action to make a perception check and draw my sword in tandem with that action.
>
> DM: (thinking to himself) *phew, rules crisis averted. I can't imagine what wild unforeseen things might have happened if I had let them draw their sword without taking an action*.

Just get your sword out and move on with your turn please.

Comment: To throw a wrench, if the spell has a Somatic component, then you need to worry about having a free hand, War Caster, and other factors.

Comment: @MivaScott Just draw your sword after you’re done with your components. Or, and this is how I rule as a DM, just draw your sword and don’t worry about this rule until you start trying to get multiple object interacts in one turn.